# Android Maps V2: Polygon fill disappears when zooming out

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

I am trying to show multiple polygons on my MapView, some of them overlap and have different colors. When I add them everything looks good, but as soon as I zoom out, many (not all) of the polygons stop being filled. Zooming back and forth and scrolling sometimes fills some of them again, but it appears to be random behavior.

The code for adding the polygons:

```
clearAreas();
for (Area area: areas) {
    for (List<LatLng> subArea: area.getSubAreas()) {
        mAreaPolygons.add(getMap().addPolygon(
             new PolygonOptions()
                .strokeWidth(2.0f)
                .zIndex(++zIndex)
                .strokeColor(area.getColor())
                .fillColor(area.getTransparentColor())
                .addAll(subArea)));
    }
}
```

I understand that (according to the documentation) a Polygon will not be filled if its geometry is not specified correctly. I tried adding the points in both clockwise and counter-clockwise order, it doesn't make a difference.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

**Update**: If the debugger is attached, everything works perfectly! The polygons are all filled and stay filled when zooming out. As soon as I detach the debugger, polygons start losing their fill again. What's going on here?

**Update #2**: The problem shows up on my Galaxy S3. Surprisingly, it works on a slower, older device! Since attaching a debugger makes the app become quite slow, maybe there is some kind of connection here?

Thanks a lot,
Marco

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with circle fill. What do you mean when the debugger is attached? A dbugger other than logcat?

Comment: Nevermind, you mean the Eclipse debugger for example. I can confirm. When running in that debug mode, the app is super slow, but all of my circle fills draw perfectly and never disappear when zooming / panning. What is going on?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm dealing with it right now.

Comment: Maybe these links can provide you an answer? 

http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/fixing-bug-with-disappearing-map-overlay-after-zoom-in-android/ 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Answer (score 0):

This reeks of threading if what you've said in your two updates is true. Somewhere you've got threading issues. With just the snippet of code you've provided, nothing looks out of place, but it would require examination of the rest of your code to figure this out. What's most likely going on is that the call to draw these polygons is starting before the view is ready to be drawn on. Without seeing anything, I'd suggest something along these lines to approach a fix:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition pos) {
    if (pos.zoom != currentZoom) {
            mMap.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // TODO: call the method that wraps the code you provided
                });
    }
});
```

What this will do is call the `Runnable` you provided here after the views are done rendering. This may not work as intended on the map view, you may have to post it into a different queue, or do some delayed posting. I'm not familiar enough with the map framework to know for sure that this will solve it, but it definitely sounds like there are threading issues here.